# Legacy Test Coverage Files

Tags: xcode8, code-coverage

I just noticed the option to 'Generate Legacy Test Coverage Files' which begs the question, what's the revised paradigm?

Is there a *revised* way of generating a physical coverage report (PDF/HTML, etc.)?

[image]